# "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream" error in FFmpeg, previous and current values are equal

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg

I have a number of `.ts` segments (AES-128 encrypted), `.m3u8` chunklist for them and a key to decrypt them.

My goal is to remux these `.ts` files into one `.mp4`. I also obviously don't want to modify the actual video/audio streams in them in any way.

I'm using the following command:

> ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i chunklist.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a copy
>   output.mp4

but getting a bunch of "Non-monotonous DTS" errors. It results in the output file experiencing dropping frames every like 3 seconds during playback.

I know this is a common issue that was discussed here many times, however, the solutions described in other questions don't seem to be working for me and also, in my case the previous and current values are equal.

Here's the console output for the first three `.ts` parts:

```
[hls,applehttp @ 0000022945ff9fc0] Opening 'key' for reading

[hls,applehttp @ 0000022945ff9fc0] Opening 'crypto:part0.ts' for reading

Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'chunklist.m3u8':   Duration: 02:34:55.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s   Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9],
29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc

    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0

Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':

  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc

    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0

Stream mapping:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)   Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[mp4 @ 00000229460c8500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: **177177**, current: **177177**; changing to **177178**. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[hls,applehttp @ 0000022945ff9fc0] Opening 'crypto:part1.ts' for reading

[mp4 @ 00000229460c8500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 357357, current: 357357; changing to 357358. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[mp4 @ 00000229460c8500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 537538, current: 537538; changing to 537539. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[hls,applehttp @ 0000022945ff9fc0] Opening 'crypto:part2.ts' for reading

[mp4 @ 00000229460c8500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 717718, current: 717718; changing to 717719. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[mp4 @ 00000229460c8500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 897898, current: 897898; changing to 897899. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

It seems like if I concatenate the `.ts` files and then remux the big `.ts` file into `.mp4` there are no dropping frames, except in the beginning where I get 2 dropped frames for some reason. VLC player also detects the frame rate as 30.05 while it should be 29.97 so... I don't think it's the perfect solution.

So I have the following questions:

1. Why these errors appear? What exactly is wrong with my `.ts` files?
2. How to remux these `.ts` files properly so no "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream" errors appear?

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/twsn7mdew9aa8lx/test.zip/file) are the files I'm working with in a zip archive. I've included only three of the .ts files there, that should be enough for a test.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to get `ffmpeg` working properly for this stream without bouncing the video to an `.h264` container. However `mkvmerge` works well once input is decrypted: `cat part<->.ts(n) | openssl enc -aes128 -d -K $(hexdump -n16 -e'16/1 "%x"' key) -iv 0 -out decrypted-parts.ts; mkvmerge -o out.mkv decrypted-parts.ts` (using linux, hence `hexdump` & `zsh`'s numerical glob sort order for that concatenation)

Comment: I tried using MKVToolNix but the resulted video still has dropping frames on plyback. Unless I use the "fix bitstream timing info" option - that seems to fix the issue but I'm not sure if it's the best solution... Still can't understand what's the issue here.